# Android application retain the state after the app is restored from minimize

Tags: android

I have an app which starts from a splash screen and then navigates to other activities. If i press the home button in a particular activity ,the app gets minimized. Again if i click on the app icon, the app starts from the splash screen. I want to resume my app from the activity in which the home button was pressed. How to achieve this?

```
   package com.xyz.user.login;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.AlertDialog;
  import android.content.DialogInterface;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuInflater;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ImageButton;

  public class ResetPasswordActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.logout:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
        PopIt("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void PopIt(String string) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(string)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    SignInActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reset_password);
     ImageButton imgRPass=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgChangePass);
     imgRPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent=new Intent(ResetPasswordActivity.this,ResetPasswordMessageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
     ImageButton imgBack=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtnBackFromResetPass);
     imgBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
            }
        });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the code in your Activities has a call to `finish()` in `onStop()` or `onPause()`. That destroys the Activity when it's minimised and causes the app to start again. There are other steps to take to be sure of restoring the state, but that is a good place to start looking.

You could try putting this code in there to track what is going on.

```
private static final String TAG = "ResetPasswordActivity";
@Override public void onStart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart:");
    super.onStart();
}  
@Override public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume:");
    super.onResume();
}
@Override public void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause:");
    super.onPause();
}
@Override public void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop:");
    super.onStop();
}
@Override public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy:");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

There are calls to `finish` and `startActivity` in there, although I cannot see why they should be executed. I'd put a `Log` statement by each. Then try it again and see what the Logcat output says when you minimise and relaunch the app.

Comment: I have an app here with an Activity that presents a FAQ screen off a menu deep in the app, and it minimises and restores to the same view with no trouble. Can you edit your question to post the code of the smallest Activity you have that you expect to restore after being minimised?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the default behavior of android. when you press home button app get minimized and when you click on app icon, by default app start from the same screen because its in pause mode and running in background. however you are getting splash screen on next launch that means your activity is getting killed by somehow either by android(due to memory constraint) or its getting a crash. see your logcat for details.

Comment: there's no abnormal behaviour in my app. During normal running of the app, if i minimize it, the app again starts from splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

Write in AndroidManifest.xml to every activity option `android:launchMode="singleTop"`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have `android:noHistory="true"` in your activity tag of manifest file. With it Android doesn't keep activity state when you minimizing your app